# Disable file close warning dialogbox in Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

I primarily use ST as my temporary notepad. Now when I hit Ctrl+W it is producing me this dialog

[image]

However 99% time my intention is "Close Without Saving". Is there a way to disable this popup? Since in reality, ST autosaves my files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can just write a plugin to set the view as scratch and close it. Then create a keybinding for that command.
Select *Tools > Developer > New Plugin...* and paste:

```py
import sublime_plugin


class CloseWithoutSavingCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        view = self.window.active_view()
        view.set_scratch(True)
        view.close()
```

Then create a keybinding to overwrite ctrl+w

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+w"],
    "command": "close_without_saving",
},
```

PS. As @Dreamcat4 mentioned in the comments it may also be relevant to limit this keybinding to temporary buffers. In that case you can easily create a context listener, which only enables the keybinding for that file type:

```py
import operator as opi

import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class CloseWithoutSavingCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        view = self.window.active_view()
        view.set_scratch(True)
        view.close()

class IsRealFileListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_query_context(self, view, key, operator, operand, match_all):
        # only act with the correct context key
        if key != 'user.is_real_file':
            return

        if operator == sublime.OP_EQUAL:
            op = opi.eq
        elif operator == sublime.OP_NOT_EQUAL:
            op = opi.ne
        else:
            # operator not supported
            return

        # assumption: a real file is a buffer, which has a filename as target
        is_real_file = bool(view.file_name())
        return op(is_real_file, operand)
```

Create a keybinding to overwrite ctrl+w, but limited to a context

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+w"],
    "command": "close_without_saving",
    "context": [
        { "key": "user.is_real_file", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ],
},
```

Comment: @itsneo Sorry I did not understand your note. This should not have a negative effect on the rest of the behavior.

Comment: Sorry about that, It's working perfectly fine, Gotta delete that comment

Comment: btw @r-stein, got paypal ? this answer deserves a bit tip :D

Comment: Thanks :). No, I don't have paypal, but I appreciate your positive feedback as a tip ;).

Comment: This is a great answer. But what if I want to make the choice dynamically, based on whether the open buffer points to a real file? As I only want to do this action when the buffer is not a real file (but I do for those temporary buffers, created on the fly).

Comment: @Dreamcat4 In that case you would just add a context to limit the keybinding. I have added that use case to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I also use Sublime as a temporary notepad.

For Macos users trying to dismiss
[this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZczL6.png), which I swear got worse over the years

- `Esc` hits "Cancel"
- `Enter` hits "Save"
- `N` *should* "Don't Save", but it doesn't

  - Arrow keys don't work either

After thinking about this for too many minutes, here's what I do now.

1. Select all `⌘A`
2. Delete `⌫`
3. Close tab `⌘W`